# How can I fix this if statement to not fail when returning null?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

> PHP Fatal error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id()
> on null

Receiving error above in woocommerce / automatewoo.

EDIT
I'm trying to end the function if `$cart_item['data']->get_id()` returns `null`:

```
 if( $value = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), 
  'printful_variant_id', null ) ){
}
         return false;
```

Current example below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_field_as_item_data', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_field_as_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
if( $value = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), 'printful_variant_id', true ) ){
    $cart_data[] = array(
        'name' => __( 'Var ID', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => sanitize_text_field( $value )
    );
    
}
return $cart_data;
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem with `get_id` *returning* `null`. It's a problem of *calling* `get_id` on `null`. Meaning `$cart_item['data']` is `null` at the moment when you try to get the id from it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that makes more sense. What would be the best approach to do nothing if `$cart_item['data']` is `null`?

Comment: Just check its value at the beginning. If it's empty, bail out of the function.

Comment: @miken32  Something like this?

 `if( $value = get_post_meta( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), null ) ){
}
 exit();`

Comment: `if (!$cart_item['data']) { return; }`

Comment: @El_Vanja Perfect. Worked. Thank you.